# How should a stateless data transformation be applied in regard to train/test split?

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, preprocessing, normalization, outlier

I want to apply spatial sign transformation to my data, but unlike other transformations this one is stateless. I am using `sklearn` and normallly i would first use the `.fit()` function on training set and then `.transfrom()` on test set, but in the documantation it says `(even though the fit method is useless in this case: the class is stateless as this operation treats samples independently)`. Since this is a transformation to reduce the influence of outliers should it be applied before the train/test split? Or should I just transform both sets independently?

The exact class i am using is [Normalizer](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.Normalizer.html#sklearn.preprocessing.Normalizer).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case it makes no difference due to the nature of the transform. It is equivalent, before/after makes no difference.